# javascript program to write data of one text file into another

Tags: node.js

I want to write a Javascript program that reads the contents from `file1.txt` and copies the content of that file into a new file named `file2.txt`.

After the task is completed, it should returns `file created`. Both of the files will be from the root directory.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
const read = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.readFile('file1.txt', 'utf8', (data) => {
            resolve(data.toString())
        })
    })
}

const copy = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.writeFile('file2.txt', read(), (err) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err)
            else
                resolve('file created')
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code for readability ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [node 8.5](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_mode_callback) you can use `copyFile` from the `fs`-module. Something like:

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function copyFile(from, destination) {
   // destination file will be overwritten/created by default
   return fs.promises.copyFile(from, destination);
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await copyFile('./file.txt', './file2.txt');
    console.log('file created');
  } catch (err) {
    //handle error
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```
var fs = require("fs");
const read = () => {

    const data = fs.readFileSync('./file1.txt', 
            {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
            console.log(data)
    return data;
};

const copy = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fs.writeFile("file2.txt", read(), (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve("file created");
    });
  });
};
copy();
```